# spree_i18n product filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, spree

I'm having an issue with the spree_I18n gem and the Spree admin panel. 
i'm trying to get the admin product filter to work on spree 3.0 stable.
I found this thread : https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_i18n/pull/602

I changed my gemfile accordingly

This is my gemfile :

```
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_i18n', git: 'https://github.com/mvz/spree_i18n.git', branch: '3-0-ransack-translations'
```

I ran bundle install and bundle update spree_i18n but The admin product filter is still returning all of the products. Is there a step that I missed ?

here are the logs :

```
Started GET "/admin/products?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bname_cont%5D=Mug&q%5Bvariants_including_master_sku_cont%5D=&q%5Bdeleted_at_null%5D=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-26 13:56:39 +0200
Processing by Spree::Admin::ProductsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"name_cont"=>"Mug", "variants_including_master_sku_cont"=>"", "deleted_at_null"=>"1"}}
  Spree::User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "spree_users".* FROM "spree_users" WHERE "spree_users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "spree_users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "spree_roles" INNER JOIN "spree_roles_users" ON "spree_roles"."id" = "spree_roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "spree_roles_users"."user_id" = $1 AND "spree_roles"."name" = $2  [["user_id", 1], ["name", "admin"]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "spree_products"."id") FROM "spree_products" WHERE "spree_products"."deleted_at" IS NULL
  Rendered /Users/stefan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree-a39d06ab644e/backend/app/views/spree/admin/shared/_index_table_options.html.erb (118.4ms)
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT count_column) FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT "spree_products"."id" AS count_column FROM "spree_products" WHERE "spree_products"."deleted_at" IS NULL LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
  Spree::Product Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "spree_products".* FROM "spree_products" WHERE "spree_products"."deleted_at" IS NULL  ORDER BY "spree_products"."name" ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  Spree::Variant Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "spree_variants".* FROM "spree_variants" WHERE "spree_variants"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "spree_variants"."is_master" = $1 AND "spree_variants"."product_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)  ORDER BY "spree_variants".position ASC  [["is_master", "f"]]
  Spree::Image Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "spree_assets".* FROM "spree_assets" WHERE "spree_assets"."type" IN ('Spree::Image') AND "spree_assets"."viewable_type" = 'Spree::Variant' AND "spree_assets"."viewable_id" IN (17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26)  ORDER BY "spree_assets"."position" ASC
  Spree::Variant Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "spree_variants".* FROM "spree_variants" WHERE "spree_variants"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "spree_variants"."is_master" = $1 AND "spree_variants"."product_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)  [["is_master", "t"]]
  Spree::Image Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "spree_assets".* FROM "spree_assets" WHERE "spree_assets"."type" IN ('Spree::Image') AND "spree_assets"."viewable_type" = 'Spree::Variant' AND "spree_assets"."viewable_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 10, 9, 8)  ORDER BY "spree_assets"."position" ASC
  Spree::Price Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "spree_prices".* FROM "spree_prices" WHERE "spree_prices"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "spree_prices"."currency" = $1 AND "spree_prices"."variant_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 10, 9, 8)  [["currency", "USD"]]
  Spree::Product::Translation Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "spree_product_translations".* FROM "spree_product_translations" WHERE "spree_product_translations"."spree_product_id" = $1  [["spree_product_id", 1]]
  Spree::Product::Translation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "spree_product_translations".* FROM "spree_product_translations" WHERE "spree_product_translations"."spree_product_id" = $1  [["spree_product_id", 2]]
  Spree::Product::Translation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "spree_product_translations".* FROM "spree_product_translations" WHERE "spree_product_translations"."spree_product_id" = $1  [["spree_product_id", 3]]
  Spree::Product::Translation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "spree_product_translations".* FROM "spree_product_translations" WHERE "spree_product_translations"."spree_product_id" = $1  [["spree_product_id", 4]]
  Spree::Product::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "spree_product_translations".* FROM "spree_product_translations" WHERE "spree_product_translations"."spree_product_id" = $1  [["spree_product_id", 5]]
  Spree::Product::Translation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "spree_product_translations".* FROM "spree_product_translations" WHERE "spree_product_translations"."spree_product_id" = $1  [["spree_product_id", 6]]
  Spree::Product::Translation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "spree_product_translations".* FROM "spree_product_translations" WHERE "spree_product_translations"."spree_product_id" = $1  [["spree_product_id", 7]]
  Spree::Product::Translation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "spree_product_translations".* FROM "spree_product_translations" WHERE "spree_product_translations"."spree_product_id" = $1  [["spree_product_id", 8]]
  Spree::Product::Translation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "spree_product_translations".* FROM "spree_product_translations" WHERE "spree_product_translations"."spree_product_id" = $1  [["spree_product_id", 9]]
  Spree::Product::Translation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "spree_product_translations".* FROM "spree_product_translations" WHERE "spree_product_translations"."spree_product_id" = $1  [["spree_product_id", 10]]
  Rendered /Users/stefan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree-a39d06ab644e/backend/app/views/spree/admin/shared/_index_table_options.html.erb (122.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/stefan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree-a39d06ab644e/backend/app/views/spree/admin/products/index.html.erb within spree/layouts/admin (370.4ms)
Deface: 1 overrides found for 'spree/admin/shared/_head'
Deface: 'override' matched 1 times with 'title'
Deface: [WARNING] No :original defined for 'override', you should change its definition to include:
 :original => 'b94dd9df96e085d9a869128fa811ee3aaf55fab1' 
Deface: 1 overrides found for 'spree/admin/shared/_translations'
Deface: 'translation' matched 1 times with 'script'
Deface: [WARNING] No :original defined for 'translation', you should change its definition to include:
 :original => '6d879f5c231ff848b4e1023dc0f8b271f922269b' 
  Rendered /Users/stefan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree-a39d06ab644e/backend/app/views/spree/admin/shared/_translations.html.erb (27.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/stefan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree-a39d06ab644e/backend/app/views/spree/admin/shared/_head.html.erb (985.0ms)
Deface: 1 overrides found for 'spree/admin/shared/_header'
Deface: 'auth_admin_login_navigation_bar' matched 1 times with '[data-hook='admin_login_navigation_bar'], #admin_login_navigation_bar[data-hook]'
Deface: [ERROR] The original source for 'auth_admin_login_navigation_bar' has changed, this override should be reviewed to ensure it's still valid.
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "spree_roles" INNER JOIN "spree_roles_users" ON "spree_roles"."id" = "spree_roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "spree_roles_users"."user_id" = $1 AND "spree_roles"."name" = $2  [["user_id", 1], ["name", "admin"]]
  Rendered /Users/stefan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree_auth_devise-2e8e08759c4d/lib/views/backend/spree/layouts/admin/_login_nav.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree-a39d06ab644e/backend/app/views/spree/admin/shared/_header.html.erb (15.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree-a39d06ab644e/backend/app/views/spree/admin/shared/sub_menu/_product.html.erb (3.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree-a39d06ab644e/backend/app/views/spree/admin/shared/sub_menu/_promotion.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Spree::Store Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "spree_stores".* FROM "spree_stores" WHERE (url like '%localhost%')  ORDER BY "spree_stores"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Spree::Store Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "spree_stores".* FROM "spree_stores" WHERE "spree_stores"."default" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_stores"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["default", "t"]]
  Spree::Country Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "spree_countries".* FROM "spree_countries" WHERE "spree_countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 232]]
  Rendered /Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree-a39d06ab644e/backend/app/views/spree/admin/shared/sub_menu/_configuration.html.erb (7.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree-a39d06ab644e/backend/app/views/spree/admin/shared/_main_menu.html.erb (106.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/stefan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree-a39d06ab644e/backend/app/views/spree/admin/shared/_content_header.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree-a39d06ab644e/backend/app/views/spree/admin/shared/_alert.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree-a39d06ab644e/backend/app/views/spree/admin/shared/_table_filter.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1711ms (Views: 1697.4ms | ActiveRecord: 6.1ms)
```

Comment: which field are you searching by name?

Comment: I added the logs. this is the field : 
<%= form_tag request.fullpath, id: "quick-search" do %>
          <%= text_field_tag :quick_search, nil, class: "form-control js-quick-search", placeholder: Spree.t(:quick_search) %>
        <% end %>